# How to register new websocket connections gofiber

Tags: go, websocket, channel, go-fiber, fasthttp

I'm trying to set up a simple websocket server that should serve the client some content at unknown intervals.

My code currently looks like this:

*router.go*

```
func SetupRoutes(app *fiber.App) error {

    app.Get("/whop/validate", handler.HandleWhopValidate)
    /*Other non-websocket routes*/

    /*...*/

    app.Get("/ws/monitor", websocket.New(wsHandler.HandleWsMonitor))

    app.Use(func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
        c.SendStatus(404)
        return c.Next()
    })

    return nil
}
```

*handler.go*

```
package handlers

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/gofiber/websocket/v2"
)

var register = make(chan *websocket.Conn)
var unregister = make(chan *websocket.Conn)

func HandleWsMonitor(c *websocket.Conn) {
    go SocketListener()
    defer func() {
        unregister <- c
        //may need to check whether connection is already closed before re-closing?
        c.Close()
    }()
    //sends conn into channel
    register <- c
    for {
        messageType, message, err := c.ReadMessage()
        if err != nil {
            if websocket.IsUnexpectedCloseError(err, websocket.CloseGoingAway, websocket.CloseAbnormalClosure) {
                log.Println("read error:", err)
            }
            return
        }
        if messageType == websocket.TextMessage {
            log.Println("got textmessage:", string(message))
        } else {
            log.Println("received message of type:", messageType)
        }
    }
}

func SocketListener() {
    for {
        select {
        case c := <-register:
            messageType, message, err := c.ReadMessage()
            if err != nil {
                log.Println(err)
                unregister <- c
                return
            }

            fmt.Printf("Got message of type: %d\nMessage:%s\n", messageType, string(message))
            fmt.Printf("Connection Params: %s\n", c.Params("id"))
            //append to list of co
        case c := <-unregister:
            //remove conection from list of clients
            c.Close()
            fmt.Printf("Closed connection\n")

        }

    }
}
```

The issue I'm having is that when I connect to the websocket, my select case for register is not hit (I'd want to register the client connection to a map using a uuid that is previously provided to the client).

*client.go*

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "log"
    "net/url"

    "github.com/fasthttp/websocket"
)

type Client struct {
    C *websocket.Conn
}

func main() {
    addr := flag.String("addr", "localhost:8080", "http service address")
    u := url.URL{
        Scheme:   "ws",
        Host:     *addr,
        Path:     "/ws/monitor",
        RawQuery: "id=12",
    }
    wsClient := &Client{}

    log.Printf("connecting to %s\n", u.String())
    // Connect to the WebSocket server
    conn, resp, err := websocket.DefaultDialer.Dial(u.String(), nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Dial:", err)
    }
    wsClient.C = conn
    if resp != nil {
        log.Println("Got response:", resp)
    }
    defer wsClient.closeConn()
}

func (client *Client) closeConn() {
    err := client.C.WriteMessage(
        websocket.CloseMessage,
        websocket.FormatCloseMessage(websocket.CloseNormalClosure, ""),
    )
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Write close:", err)
        return
    }
    client.C.Close()
    log.Println("Connection closed")
}
```

Is there something I'm missing in *handler.go* or should i just be taking a different approach when connecting to the server with my client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The select case for register did hit according to my test (the code I used is attached to the bottom of this answer).

But I found other issues in the code:

1. The `unregister` chan is unbuffered, and `unregister <- c` in `SocketListener` will be blocked. When the code reaches `unregister <- c`, there is a deadlock between it and `case c := <-unregister`.
2. It seems we only need one `SocketListener` goroutine for the whole server. If this is the case, it should be moved outside of `HandleWsMonitor`.
3. Both `HandleWsMonitor` and `SocketListener` read from the connection. What's the responsibility of `SocketListener`? It seems that it should not read from the connection.

Thinking it more, it seems that you can add connections to and delete connections from the map in `HandleWsMonitor` directly. `SocketListener` can be removed entirely. Simplicity should be a key goal in design. See the [KISS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"

    "github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2"
    "github.com/gofiber/websocket/v2"
)

var (
    register   = make(chan *websocket.Conn)
    unregister = make(chan *websocket.Conn)
)

func main() {
    // Make it easy to find out which line prints the log.
    log.SetFlags(log.Lshortfile)
    app := fiber.New()

    app.Get("/ws/monitor", websocket.New(HandleWsMonitor))

    log.Fatal(app.Listen(":8080"))
}

func HandleWsMonitor(c *websocket.Conn) {
    // It seems the we only need one SocketListener goroutine for the whole server.
    // If this is the case, the next line should be moved outside of this func.
    go SocketListener()
    defer func() {
        unregister <- c
        c.Close()
    }()

    register <- c
    for {
        messageType, message, err := c.ReadMessage()
        if err != nil {
            if websocket.IsUnexpectedCloseError(err, websocket.CloseGoingAway, websocket.CloseAbnormalClosure) {
                log.Println("read error:", err)
            }
            return
        }
        if messageType == websocket.TextMessage {
            log.Println("got textmessage:", string(message))
        } else {
            log.Println("received message of type:", messageType)
        }
    }
}

func SocketListener() {
    for {
        select {
        case c := <-register:
            // This did appear in the log.
            log.Println("case c := <-register")
            messageType, message, err := c.ReadMessage()
            if err != nil {
                log.Println(err)
                // unregister is unbuffered, the sending will be blocked.
                unregister <- c
                // If we use only one SocketListener goroutine then it should
                // not return here.
                return
            }

            log.Printf("Got message of type: %d\nMessage:%s\n", messageType, string(message))
            log.Printf("Connection Params: %s\n", c.Params("id"))
        case c := <-unregister:
            c.Close()
            log.Println("Closed connection")

        }
    }
}
```